# Vue.js what's the difference of $emit and $dispatch?

Tags: javascript, events, mvvm, vue.js, vuejs2

In vue2.0 the event `$dispatch` and `$broadcast` is deprecated.

And I found that `$dispatch` is similar with `$emit`.

What's the differences between them? Is it safe directly replacing `$dispatch` into `$emit` when migrating.

Comment: Vue 2.* has removed `$dispatch` and `$broadcast`. They now recommend using an event hub. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, You will not be able to replace `$disptach` with `$emit` everywhere. You can replace it, wherever you are using it for communication from **child to parent**, but for other cases, you may have to take some other approach.

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced) ( similar comments from Evan you in [Upgrade Tips](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873)):

> One of the most common uses for these methods is to communicate between a parent and its direct children. In these cases, you can actually listen to an $emit from a child with v-on. This allows you to keep the convenience of events with added explicitness.
>
> However, when communicating between distant descendants/ancestors, $emit won’t help you. Instead, the simplest possible upgrade would be to use a centralized event hub.

From the documentation of [$dispatch](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#vm-dispatch)

> Dispatch an event, first triggering it on the instance itself, and then propagates upward along the parent chain. The propagation stops when it triggers a parent event listener, unless that listener returns true.

on the other hand [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit):

> Trigger an event on the current instance. Any additional arguments will be passed into the listener’s callback function.

So you can see, **if you are passing communication to multiple layer of parent elements via `$dispatch`, you have to handle that code differently with `$emit`**

Comment: Ok, it means `$emit` only passes to itself and its parent, while `$dispatch` passes with bubbling up, is it right?

Comment: In context of parent child communication: Yes, However there are other uses of $emit also, which you can explore in [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication). But as you are migrating from vue 1, you need to consider this difference of chain propagation.

Comment: example codepen of a simple Vue element that acts as an eventBus ($on, $emit) https://codepen.io/intosite/pen/WxQZvq