# Vue.js 2 pass data from component to root instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that makes an AJAX request. In the callback function I want to pass a value back to the parent or root instance.

So my callback function for example in the component is:

```
function callbackFunc(vm, response){
  vm.$emit('setValue', response.id);
}
```

and in my root instance I've tried using a method called setValue like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      value : ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setValue: function(value){
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. The documentation seems to say you need to have an event inside the template for it all to get hooked up but that's not going to work in this case.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? How is your callback getting called etc.

Comment: It's literarly just a function on it's own in the global scope. vm is a reference to the vue instance so that $emit can be called.

Comment: If it's in the global scope, why not just something like `const app = new Vue(...)` and in `callbackFunc` use `app.setValue(response.id)`.

Comment: Updated my question with the full root instance. How would I get it to work with that? Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js what's the difference of $emit and $dispatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923555/vue-js-whats-the-difference-of-emit-and-dispatch)

Comment: You need to use your component.$on("setValue") (setValue being the event you just emitted) and call your own method from this one.

Comment: Cheers, I don't follow that. Can you expand your answer a bit?

Comment: I really can't picture your structure here. You said the ajax call is made in a component, but the callback is in the global scope, and it looks like you are using single file components.

Comment: Yes the ajax call is made in a component, the ajax call's callback function is placed in the global scope. I'm using a vue-cli template so each "page" is using it's own component.

Comment: And the callback is defined in the same file as the component that is making the ajax call or in the main.js? `vm` is the component?

Comment: You may want to use Vuex to share the data with other components.

Comment: Same file as the component. To be honest I'm probably getting myself confused with the vue-cli project structure.

Comment: Is the component a direct child of the app component?

Comment: See this is where I'm confused. I'm using vue-router. So there's the root element that has an App component and then there's the component called Hello which has the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using vue-router. So there's the root element that has an App
>   component and then there'sthe component called Hello which has the
>   ajax call

In the parent component's template you will have a `<router-view><\router-view>` which is where the vue-router will put your child. To wire everything up, you need to add the directive to the template:

```
<router-view v-on:setValue="parentMethod" ><\router-view>
```

When the child calls `$emit("setValue")` after the ajax call, it will triggers `parentMethod()` on the parent. It's not clear why you say it won't work to hook it up in the template. Without the template, there's not really a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Cheers! Trying this now. I'm getting: Property or method "parentMethod" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Comment: Sorry I fixed that. Amazing, that works! Thank you! I understand what's going on better now. I thought I needed to have it binded to like a click event or blur or something. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry - that wasn't clear. I meant `parentMethod` in a generic method on your parent. You need to write this method on your parent and call it something like parentMethod or even `setValue()` The template is telling your parent component to listen for the event `setValue` and then call some method on the parent.

Comment: Glad it's working. In Vue and also (Angular) getting the parent/child one-way communication took me a couple tries before it 'clicked'

Comment: Yeah that was crazy confusing for me! Thanks again!

Comment: One hopefully quick follow up question. If I want to get the value I set in the parent component in another child how would I do that?

Comment: You pass data from parent to child with props. So you would have something like `<router-view v-on:setValue="parentMethod" :data="parentVariable">` Then in the child you would pick it up by defining props with ` props: ['data']` which you can then use like an instance variable.  Had to explain in this little space, but good examples here:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props